# Use a .html file and use variables

Tags: php, html, variables

Say i have a .html file that contains a web design and has variables in it like $time $comment $title.

how would i enter them variables from a php file

Sorry i cannot really explain it well enough but i hope somebody understands

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is hard to understand. Please edit the question to add much more detail so we can understand better.

Comment: So your question is more: "How do I use a plain HTML file as PHP template?" ?

Comment: do you think of a template system where $time is replaced by the time the post was added ex.

Comment: If you cannot explain, that is maybe because you don't understand your problem fully. If you don't know what the problem is, it will be hard for us to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. I'll just guess what you want.  Since the question isn't very clear.

In a PHP script, load the HTML in with something like file_get_contents, then use str_replace to replace the 'variables' in the HTML, then echo the new HTML.

Or, don't use an HTML file, use a PHP file, and just use echo where you want the variables to be.

Or... use something like smarty templates which is probably more advanced than you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

1. Learn [PHP](http://php.net)
2. Learn an [MVC Framework](http://www.mustap.com/phpzone_post_73_top-10-php-mvc-frameworks) of your choice
3. Change the .html file into .php
4. Put it in with your "Views"
5. Call it from your Controller (defining your view variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can get apache to parse .html files as PHP by adding this directive to your .htaccess (or httpd.conf):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

It might be necessary to change this line in your httpd.conf:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

That will enable .htaccess overrides to the apache configuration.

This answer assumes two things:

1 - That I understood the question.

2 - That you are in fact using Apache web server.

Comment: This solution is troublesome though in the sense that it will unnecessarily and incorrectly parse HTML files as PHP. If a script is ever installed on the server which allows users to upload HTML files, this can allow for an attack by having "HTML files" that are running as scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I also take a chance that I understand you right. If you think of a template system for PHP, I recommend you [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), which makes it very easy to divide HTML from php

**Why would I use Smarty (when PHP is a template engine)?**

> Some might argue that Smarty does what
>   PHP can do already: separate the
>   presentation from business logic. The
>   PHP programming language is great for
>   code development but when mixed with
>   HTML, the syntax of PHP statements can
>   be a mess to manage. Smarty makes up
>   for this by insulating PHP from the
>   presentation with a much simpler
>   tag-based syntax. The tags reveal
>   application content, enforcing a clean
>   separation from PHP (application)
>   code. No PHP knowledge is required to
>   manage Smarty templates.

Comment: Having worked with a large application that formerly used Smarty and now uses PHP itself as the templating language, I can say that it is now much faster and also easier to manage. Smarty is unnecessary bloat and should really be avoided at all costs. Strongly recommend not to use it.

Comment: I've used Smarty much before when I use php for several years for several of my customers and some own projects. I am very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a utilization problem. As others have noted, static html files are just returned as such, static files. If you want the variables replaced whenever those files are accessed, then define a handler like that from your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule (.+\.html) vars.php?file=$1
```

And a template function (`vars.php`) to works on those placeholders:

```
<?php
    // define all placeholder variables here
    $html = file_get_contents(basename($_GET["file"]));
    print preg_replace('/\$(\w+)/e', '$GLOBALS["$1"]', $html);
?>
```

But it's certainly easier to just rename your .html files into .php, and put a heredoc around them:

```
<?php
  echo<<<END
    <html>$vars</html> ...
  END;
?>
```

Comment: Probably better and more maintainable to use echo short tags `<html><?=$vars=?></html>`, as it presents fewer maintainability problems.

Comment: @yc: Indeed. I have a small script that rewrites back and forth between smarty-style variables and `<?=` output. But heredoc templates are quite readable too.